# Sets/Maps iterators not incrementable

Tags: c++, dictionary, set

Why can't I edit a set/map while iterating on it?
Example:

```
bool flag;
set <int> :: iterator aIterator;
set <int> :: iterator bIterator;
bIterator = B.begin();
for (bIterator=B.begin(); bIterator!=B.end(); ++bIterator)
{
    flag = true;
    aIterator = A.begin(); 
    for (aIterator=A.begin(); aIterator!=A.end(); ++aIterator)
    {
        if (*bIterator == *aIterator)// if an elemnet in B is found in A, delete that element from A and check the next element of B
        {           
            A.erase(aIterator);
            flag = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    if (flag == true)
        A.insert(*bIterator); //if not found then add that element to A(which now represents the set of symmetric difference)
}
```

and how can I handle that? I mean, how can I edit a set while iterating?

Comment: in your second loop, do you mean to use aIterator?

Comment: BTW, you may use `std::find` instead of your loop and flag variable.

Comment: yeah, that would be better in terms of the algorithm complexity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:
`for (aIterator=A.begin(); aIterator!=A.end(); ++aIterator)`

not that:
`for (bIterator=A.begin(); bIterator!=A.end(); ++aIterator)`

aIterator is not intialized, you can't increment it.

The rest of it looks ok.